# Node tmp folder and path?

Tags: node.js

In Nodejs, when running

```
fs.readdirSync('/tmp');
```

I get result like:

```
['launchd-493.Je0U5v','npm-898-26dc6432']
```

Where is this /tmp folder? what does its path look like? (I'm using OSX)

The reason I'm asking this question is because I'm build a node app on a web host which has a read-only-files system in the node app folder, and I need to save some tmp files which is then uploaded to a backend like Parse.

Thanks!

Comment: `/tmp` folder in `/tmp` obviously, and its path looks like `/tmp`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most servers should use the system temp folder; `/tmp` on OS X aliases to `/private/tmp`, which has the default permissions: `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel`.

Unless your server is abnormally locked down, you should be able to use it.

You may want to consider something like [`tmp`](https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp) as well which is tailored for temporary storage.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! The problem is the web server is in fact built on a distributed system, which means files in /tmp might be gone any moment after you save, or you whole app is transfered to another machine... At least this is my understanding

Comment: You could build a [writable memory stream](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-19-nodejs-writable-streams.html#creating_writable_memory_stream) too.

Comment: Thank you! That is absolutely doable. What if the file you are writing into the memory is very large (like HD video, etc.)?

Comment: Then... well, you probably want disk caching for that, and you'll have to overcome your distributed system's restrictions (e.g. write to a location where you can control the ephemerality of the data. That said, if you had enough money to throw at it, you could do it all in memory too.